# Changing slides on mouseover in Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have several div's on my bootstrap carousel, some kind of a navigation buttons.

What I need is changing slides on mouseover.

Like on this websites: magnatek.nichost.ru and vnka.ru

How this can be done?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: show some code, don't just ask for the solution. Try something first. Maybe start reading the docs relating to the bootstrap slider

Comment: have any JSfiddle?

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/SwVYsZx9dS  mouseover on links 1,2,3 should changing the slides, and click on links 1,2,3 should works as usual.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-01.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                 <h4>First Thumbnail label</h4>

                <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-02.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                 <h4>Second Thumbnail label</h4>

                <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-03.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                 <h4>Third Thumbnail label</h4>

                <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>

</div>
```

Script

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: false
});

var i;

$('.carousel-control').on("mouseover", function () {
    var control = $(this),
        interval = 500;

    i = setInterval(function () {
        control.trigger("click");
    }, interval);
})
.on("mouseout", function () {
    clearInterval(i);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not what I am looking for. I need changing slides on mouseover on my div's, not on control arrows.

Comment: You need to just change jquery 

$('.carousel-control').on("mouseover", function () {
replace with following code
$('.carousel-inner').on("mouseover", function () {


Also replace HTML 
<div class="carousel-inner">
replace with 
<div class="carousel-inner" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">

Answer (score 0):

You need to just change jquery

```
$('.carousel-control').on("mouseover", function () {
replace with following code
$('.carousel-inner').on("mouseover", function () {
```

Also replace HTML

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
replace with 
<div class="carousel-inner" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
```